# Magento: insert new product

Tags: products, query

I tried to insert a new product

```
<?php
require_once("../app/Mage.php");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
try{
$product
//    ->setStoreId(1) //you can set data in store scope
    ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
    ->setAttributeSetId(9) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
    ->setTypeId('simple') //product type
    ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product creation time
    ->setUpdatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product update time
    ->setSku('testsku61') //SKU
    ->setName('test product21') //product name
    ->setWeight(4.0000)
    ->setStatus(1) //product status (1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
    ->setTaxClassId(4) //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
    ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) //catalog and search visibility
    ->setManufacturer(28) //manufacturer id
    ->setColor(24)
    ->setNewsFromDate('06/26/2014') //product set as new from
    ->setNewsToDate('06/30/2014') //product set as new to
    ->setCountryOfManufacture('AF') //country of manufacture (2-letter country )
    ->setPrice(11.22) //price in form 11.22
    ->setCost(22.33) //price in form 11.22
    ->setSpecialPrice(00.44) //special price in form 11.22
    ->setSpecialFromDate('06/1/2014') //special price from (MM-DD-YYYY)
    ->setSpecialToDate('06/30/2014') //special price to (MM-DD-YYYY)
    ->setMsrpEnabled(1) //enable MAP
    ->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(1) //display actual price (1 - on gesture, 2 - in cart, 3 - before order confirmation, 4 - use config)
    ->setMsrp(99.99) //Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price
    ->setMetaTitle('test meta title 2')
    ->setMetaKeyword('test meta keyword 2')
    ->setMetaDescription('test meta description 2')
    ->setDescription('This is a long description')
    ->setShortDescription('This is a short description')
     ->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ())) //media gallery initialization
    ->addImageToMediaGallery('IMG_0339.JPG', array('image','thumbnail','small_image'), false, false) //assigning image, thumb and small image to media gallery
     ->setStockData(array(
                       'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                       'manage_stock'=>1, //manage stock
                       'min_sale_qty'=>1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                       'max_sale_qty'=>2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                       'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                       'qty' => 999 //qty
                   )
    )
    ->setCategoryIds(array(3, 10)); //assign product to categories
$product->save();
//endif;
}catch(Exception $e){
Mage::log($e->getMessage());
echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

but the error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`db_db`.`catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set`
>   (`attribute_set_id`)), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity`
>   (`entity_type_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `type_id`, `sku`, `created_at`,
>   `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, '2015-10-08 08:09:50', '2015-10-08
>   08:09:50')

What is the problem? I have setting the sku code and the other fields.

Comment: please check attribute_set is proper or  not

Comment: Default attribute set id in a stock magento installation is 4, you can also use Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getDefaultAttributeSetId() instead of hard-coding it.